# VLC black screen on videos

Tags: video, media, vlc

i've just installed the last version of raspian desktop on my new raspberry. I did the update and upgrade and i did a reboot. I installed VLC and i copyed a film .avi in the microsd card in the videos folder. When i double click the file VLC starts but the screen of the program stay black. The audio start but not the video. If i skip and go, for exemple, at the half of the film and image, like a frame, of the film compares but it stay freeze to that frame but the audio still go ahead. How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for this, Try with another video file with lower resolution if it works then maybe your file got damaged after transferring to SD card.

Comment: Tryed with another video file and same error. It is not file damaged

Comment: I think it is something with the HDMI.